# Set current location as default value in TextField Autocomplete Material UI

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, material-ui

How to set defaultValue to current location into TexField inside AutoComplete form from Material UI.
I have fetched current location using Geolocaction

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
    console.log("position",position);
    console.log("Latitude is :", position.coords.latitude);
    console.log("Longitude is :", position.coords.longitude);
      // Get address from latidude & longitude.
Geocode.fromLatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude).then(
  response => {
 setAddress(response.results[0].formatted_address);
  },
  error => {
    console.error(error);
  }
);
  });
```

I am using autocomplete form from MATERIAL UI. I have tried to write `defaultValue={addresss}` but nothing happens.

```
<Autocomplete
          id="google-map-demo"
          getOptionLabel={(option) =>
            typeof option === "string" ? option : option.description
          }
          filterOptions={(x) => x}
          options={options}
          onChange={(e, v) => {
            user.setFulladdress(v.description);
            getPlace(v.place_id);
          }}
          renderInput={(params) => (
            <TextField
              {...params}
              placeholder="Address"
              defaultValue={address}
              InputProps={{
                ...params.InputProps,
                classes: {
                  input: classes.resize,
                },
                disableUnderline: true,
            }}
              variant="standard"
              fullWidth
              onChange={(e, v) => {
                setInputValue(e.target.value);
              }}
             
            />
```

Anyone idea how to put default value as current location of user?

Comment: Can you provide jsfiddle?